# Change DOM position of dynamically created labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I need to style some CMS generated labels and input fields. This is the markup for each element(there are five in total).

```
<br>
<label>City of birth:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" maxlength="200" name="os5">
```

I need to add class to each of the inputs, that is easy. I also need to put each label right after the corresponding input. I am able to target each label with this code, just for example.

```
$('label:nth-of-type(2)').css('color','blue');
```

This way I can target each five labels, but I can't find a way to move each label, right after the corresponding input field.

Comment: How do the `label` elements 'correspond' to the `input` elements? There should be a `for` attribute in the `label` and an `id` on the `input` in order to associate them.

Comment: They are not actual form elements, they are used for custom text messages, for product in a shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the collection to get each one individually using [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each), at which point [`.nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll) will let you find the appropriate following `<input>` and [`.after`](https://api.jquery.com/after) can be used to move its label.

```
$('label:nth-of-type(2)')
    .css('color', 'blue')
    .each(function () {
        var $label = $(this);
        var $input = $label.nextAll('input').eq(0);

        $input.after($label);
    });
```

Keep in mind that the appropriate thing to do is probably identify your labels better, and make sure that they’re associated with the form fields using `<label>`’s `for` attribute (but pick a better class name):

```
<label class="move-label" for="city-of-birth">City of birth:</label>
⋮
<input type="text" name="os5" id="city-of-birth" maxlength="200" />
```

And then you can do this, which I think is better =)

```
var labels = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName('move-label')
    );

labels.forEach(function (label) {
    var associatedElement = document.getElementById(label.htmlFor);

    label.parentNode.insertBefore(associatedElement, label.nextSibling);
});
```

… though jQuery works too:

```
$('.move-label').each(function () {
    var $input = $(document.getElementById(this.htmlFor));

    $input.after(this);
});
```

… and if you were golfing it:

```
$('.move-label').each(function () {
    $('#' + this.htmlFor).after(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the following `input` sibling:

```
$('label:nth-of-type(2)').each(function() {
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).nextAll('input:first'));
});
```